# Swift UIImage Animation - Fly in from outside of frame into frame

Tags: swift, animation, uiimage, uiviewanimation

I am currently trying to see if there are any tutorials or some reference on how to animate UIImages to fly in from outside of frame into frame. I am currently trying to use the bottom code but it isn't producing what I would like.

I am creating a DC Universe intro page where the main characters will fly in one at a time and form a nice collection of characters which I think would be really cool.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.superManImage.frame.origin.x -= 200 }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your code? Is your UIImageView not flying into thee view but still animating? Is it animating at all? A little more clarity would help us help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This so far is working for me. Batman image flys in from top and Superman image flys in from left.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    superManImage.center.x -= view.bounds.width
    batManImage.center.y -= view.bounds.width

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.8, delay: 1.0, options: [], animations: {
        self.superManImage.center.x += self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, options: [], animations: {
        self.batManImage.center.y += self.view.bounds.width
    }, completion: nil)
}
```